# possible to support protobuf-net and json clients through servicestack?

Tags: servicestack

Can you pass around protobuf messages server side and get ServiceStack to translate it to JSON for JavaScript and keep it as protobuf for non-JavaScript clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) supports having the same service being called via ProtoBuf and JSON endpoints, yes.

But there's no magic translation between ProtoBuf and JSON wire formats, your service simply returns JSON when called by a JSON ServiceClient or HTTP Client (e.g. jQuery), likewise it will return the Protocol Buffers format when called by the ProtoBufServiceClient.

Comment: is servicestack web method based rather than message based?  Also, is ProtoBufServiceClient only implented in .cs at the moment?  ty